# Docker Hub vs Docker Trusted Registry DTR

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, dockerhub

I'm about to configure my DTR "Docker Trusted Registry" for the first time and it seems complicated.

So before making an entire decision, I want to know what is the difference between "Docker Hub" and "Docker Trusted Registry"?

Thank you

Comment: Looks to me like it's just an on-premises version, for folks who need that.

Comment: ok, but why should I need to configure my DTR server as node on UCP (Docker Universal Control Plane). When should I use swarm, replicas, ... [https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/ucp/1.1/installation/install-production/]

Comment: Swarm mode is a prerequisite for installing UCP, and UCP is a prerequisite for installing DTR.

Comment: Yea when you install DTR it actually uses EE to deploy it.  Docker EE is for cloud and on-prem. One reason for using it in cloud is not to be cloud-vendor dependent.

Answer (score 5):

Docker Hub is a SaaS based solution hosted in the cloud where you have public and optionally paid private repositories.

DTR is part of the on-premises enterprise edition (EE) solution. It consist of:

- a supported docker engine that updates less frequently than the community edition and includes 1 year of support for any given release.
- using swarm mode for scheduling services
- support for Kubernetes has just been added in the 2.0 release
- UCP (universal control plane) for RBAC security
- DTR (docker trusted registry) for an enterprise registry

Over the self hosted free registry, DTR adds RBAC security that piggy backs on UCP, image scanning of all the layers of the image against well known vulnerability databases, replication for HA, built in garbage collection of deleted images, image promotion policies, and multiple storage backends to keep your image data in an HA location. The first two (RBAC and vulnerability scanning) are the main features enterprises are looking for when selecting DTR in addition to the commercial support provided by Docker Inc.